# send the form and remain on page

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I create a form to send the contact data. I want to the client send the form and remain in the main page (index.html). Here the php code:

PHP:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
     echo"<script>alert('message send succesfully')</script>";
else
    echo"<script>alert('message not send')</script>";
```

Comment: use google and do some effort https://www.google.com/search?site=webhp&source=hp&q=contact+form+with+ajax+and+php&oq=contact+form+with+aja&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l3j0i22i30l7.1345265.1349238.0.1350971.29.27.2.0.0.0.1068.4877.13j7j4j6-1j1.26.0....0...1c.1.38.hp..11.18.1334.0.9vl_3sjCrDs

Comment: Simple answer: Put the same page in the form `action`. Advanced: Use AJAX.

Comment: irrelevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Change to index.php

Add this

```
// 'to' should be the name of your input field
if (!empty($_POST['to'])) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
        echo"<script>alert('message send succesfully');</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo"<script>alert('message not send');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but is not working. Nor I can put the same page in the  action because then it would not recognize the php (contact.php)

Comment: please add your full html code. I updated the js code and added ;